# I've added graphql-codegen to my create-react-app project, but it slows starting my local development server to a crawl. Is there a way around this?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, create-react-app, react-apollo, graphql-codegen

So I've followed a few tutorials on how to get graphql-codegen to work and I'm fetching my schema from my backend server. This all works and I have a generated directory of my types, queries, and mutations.

However, when I want to start my server, I'm stuck on

```
Starting the development server...
```

I've tried adding this to my start script:

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start --max_old_space_size=8096",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "codegen": "graphql-codegen --config graphql.config.yaml"
  },
```

But nothing seems to start. It opens a new tab in my chrome browser, but nothing loads.

I've switched to another branch to see if this was specifically a codegen issue and I was able to get things running.

I don't even get any error to point me in any direction. Has anyone run into this sort of thing?